# How to keep pod if jenkins pipeline is failure

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

is there a way to keep jenkins slave pod if jenkins pipeline is failure?

I tried `podRetention: onFailure()`, but according to [jenkins jira](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60249):

> it will keep the pods only if the pods are in failure or unknow state,
> not the job

Answer (score 0):

Please try with podRetention always().
Example which works for me below:

```
kubernetes {
         cloud 'ci-build'
         defaultContainer 'shell'
         podRetention always()
         yaml podTemplate ...
```